# Getting undefined on document load in useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using reactJS with typescript. I am trying to get the height and width of the `div` using `useRef` on load after getting the height and width I am doing immediate processing on something else.

I tried two ways.

The first one is:

```
const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

const [height, setHeight] = useState(
        divRef.current?.getBoundingClientRect().height
);
```

If I `console.log(height)` I am getting `undefined`

I also tried via `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const height = setHeight(divRef.current?.getBoundingClientRect().height);
    },[]);
```

this also gives `undefined` on console.log

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your problem is the fact that divRef is null (as you defined) on its initialization, and when you write `div.ref.current?.bla` it doesn't exists so you get undefined (the elements didn't render on the screen yet)

In the second way, the useEffect does happen after the elements has rendered on the screen, and only once in your case.
where are you trying to print it? because I'm pretty sure that if you will try and print the 'height' (the one from the state you declared) above the return, it should print the value.
besides, you don't need the `const height = ...`
just the `setHeight(...)`

please let me know if it still doesn't work.